# I can't upload image to jsp page even though the method called in "src" field returns the image url

Tags: java, image, jsp

I have a Dynamic Web Project that uses Jsp pages. I have the class `Product` that has a method `getProductImage()` that returns the image url that is stored for every product in a MySql database.

In my jsp file I tried to upload the image twice - first is with it's own url and the second has the url returned from the method.

Relevant code:

```
<% for(Product u : list) 
    { %>
<a><img alt="Poza1" style="width: 270px; height: 180px;" src="<% u.getProductImage();%>"></a> 
<a><img alt="Poza2" style="width: 270px; height: 180px;"src="./images/1.jpg"></a> <br>
Nume Produs: <%= u.getProductName()%><br>
Stoc produs: <%= u.getProductStock()%><br> 
Imagine: "<%= u.getProductImage()%>"<br>
<%} %> `
```

[image: This is what it responds after I run the code]

As you can see I printed what the method returns in the last row of the image that I uploaded. Why doesn't my picture upload with the url from the method?

Comment: You are missing `=` in `src` attribute of the first image. I.e. `src="<% u.getProductImage();%>"` has to be `src="<%= u.getProductImage() %>"` (as in the last line). If you checked the generated code, you should see it.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you very much, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jozef Chocholacek found and solved the problem:

```
 You are missing = in src attribute of the first image. I.e. src="<% u.getProductImage();%>" 
has to be src="<%= u.getProductImage() %>" (as in the last line). 
If you checked the generated code, you should see it.
```

Thank you, Jozef!